# Problem in installing phpstorm-8.0.1

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded a file named *PhpStorm-8.0.1.tar.gz* , in downloads folder , and I don't know how to install this file . Also it don't contain any file with `.sh` format.

Answer (score 0):

According to instructions in https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/ PhpStorm.sh should be in the bin subdirectory

Comment: No . its not !!

Comment: I can see it in PhpStorm-139.732\bin

Comment: I am only having ,"idea.properties" and "log.xml" .

Comment: i think that the archive must be damaged , so it doesnt contain "phpstorm.sh" file

Comment: I will download a fresh new file and try .

Comment: Think so too. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the file `Install-Linux-tar.txt` lays out the steps as follows:

> ### Linux Installation Instructions
>
> 1. Unpack the PhpStorm distribution archive that you downloaded to
>       where you wish to install the program. We will refer to this destination
>       location as your {installation home} below.
> 2. Open a console and cd into "{installation home}/bin" and type:
>
>    ./phpstorm.sh
>
>    to start the application.
> 3. [OPTIONAL] Add the "{installation home}/bin" to your PATH environmental
>       variable so that you may start PhpStorm from any directory.
> 4. [OPTIONAL] To adjust the value of JVM heap size open phpstorm.vmoptions
>       (phpstorm64.vmoptions for 64-bit JDK), and modify the -Xms and -Xmx parameters.
>
>    [OPTIONAL] Changing location of "config" and "system" directory
>      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------   By default PhpStorm stores all your settings under ~/.WebIde80/config
>      directory   and stores data cache under ~/.WebIde80/system directory. 
>      If you want to change these settings,
> 5. Open a console and cd into "{installation home}/bin"
> 6. Open file "idea.properties" in an editor. You should find strings like
>
>    idea.system.path=~/.WebIde/system
>
>    and
>
>    idea.config.path=~/.WebIde/config
>
>    and change them.
> 7. Note that we recommend to store data cache ("system" directory) at a disk 
>       with at least 1G bytes free space

I have copied the extracted folder to the `/opt` directory and then run the `phpstorm.sh` file from there. This setup works fine for me.

Comment: But i had searched for the file "phpstorm.sh" in the archive but it is not present there .

Comment: @KICKBUTTOWSKI, Did you extract the contents of the archive ( PhpStorm-8.0.1.tar.gz )?

Comment: Yes, using the Archive Manager .

Comment: @KICKBUTTOWSKI, What is the size of the archive file?

Comment: Same problem with me, please help guys...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

Same issue was with me, I was trying download manager(FlareGet) to download PhpStorm but when I downloaded the file with firefox, file was ok and I got **PhpStorm.sh** file in there.